Java Selenium: "No such execution context" exception in one (or several) of my threads while trying to scrape the webpage
I am using Java 17.0.7 with Selenium 4.19.1.
First of all, here is the code I've written:
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread sessionOneThread = new Thread(() -> executeSession("Смартфон", "Session One"));
        Thread sessionTwoThread = new Thread(() -> executeSession("Годинник", "Session Two"));
        Thread sessionThreeThread = new Thread(() -> executeSession("Ноутбук", "Session Three"));

        sessionOneThread.start();
        sessionTwoThread.start();
        sessionThreeThread.start();
    }

    public static void executeSession(String searchQuery, String sessionName) {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized", "--guest");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        try {
            driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/ua/");

            WebElement searchInput =
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
                            (By.cssSelector(".search-form__input")));

            searchInput.sendKeys(searchQuery);
            searchInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

            List<WebElement> pageElements =
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy
                            (By.cssSelector(".goods-tile__content")));

            Map<String, String> pageMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (WebElement element : pageElements) {
                WebElement titleElement = element.findElement(By.cssSelector(".goods-tile__title"));
                WebElement priceElement = element.findElement(By.cssSelector(".goods-tile__price-value"));

                String title = titleElement.getText().trim();
                String price = priceElement.getText().trim();

                pageMap.put(title, price);
            }

            printResults(sessionName, pageMap);

        } finally {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    public static void printResults(String sessionName, Map<String, String> data) {
        System.out.println("Results for " + sessionName + ":");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getKey() + ", Price: " + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


The goal is to open three parallel threads, search for a specific item, and retrieve its title and price. Very simple.
Now the problem is that sometimes it just doesn't work. Sometimes it does, sometimes not. And when it doesn't - certain browser windows get parsed and close automatically, while others seem to load the page, yet nothing gets closed nor scraped, instead I get the "no such execution context" exception. And I may also get the StaleElementReferenceException, especially when both threads manage to fail at the same time. And I really can't get behind this problem.
I would appreciate if someone points at any potential problems in my code, because I found myself unable to figure it out on my own.
Here is a video demonstration of my problem:
--> YouTube link <--
I run it three times. It failed twice, and succeeded once.
No such execution context exception error log:
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: no such execution context
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=123.0.2420.65)
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [0b4fb4bfddb7c01b95fa1290d7996f5f, clickElement {id=f.2047D5BB279D97BBA968AEA56212CFCD.d.21E45996CD2BC2E8365AADF4ECD43176.e.35}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: 123.0.2420.65, fedcm:accounts: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58002}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 123.0.2420.65 (49b6a5859239..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ENROUT~1\AppData\L...}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:58002/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.2420.65, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[EdgeDriver: MicrosoftEdge on windows (0b4fb4bfddb7c01b95fa1290d7996f5f)] -> xpath: //button[contains(@class, 'search-form__submit')]]
Session ID: 0b4fb4bfddb7c01b95fa1290d7996f5f
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:76)
    at nltu.task11.App.searchAndRetrieveData(App.java:34)
    at nltu.task11.App.executeSessionThree(App.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

StaleElementReferenceException error log:
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=123.0.2420.65)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [1361c295cd46263dc225417f2dbc8f08, getElementText {id=f.4CAC34CAB98D2D0552960E68DF18F862.d.53D0E5A121385BF7622766ADC3279883.e.182}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: 123.0.2420.65, fedcm:accounts: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61353}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 123.0.2420.65 (49b6a5859239..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ENROUT~1\AppData\L...}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:61353/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.2420.65, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[[[EdgeDriver: MicrosoftEdge on windows (1361c295cd46263dc225417f2dbc8f08)] -> css selector: .goods-tile__content]] -> xpath: .//span[@class='goods-tile__price-value']]
Session ID: 1361c295cd46263dc225417f2dbc8f08
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:191)
    at nltu.task11.App.searchAndRetrieveData(App.java:48)
    at nltu.task11.App.executeSessionTwo(App.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I tried:

Explicit waits (many kinds of them)
Replacing Selenium queries with JavaScript executor
Using Chrome and Firefox drivers instead of Edge
Searching for similar problems on the internet
Using AI for troubleshooting and suggestions (in vain)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
